# What is the difference between len() and count()?

Tags: rust

In code below, I get the same result whether I use `len` or `count`:

```
fn main() {
    let vector = [0, 1, 2];
    assert_eq!(vector.iter().count(), vector.iter().len());
}
```

`len` seems more generic since I can also do this:

```
assert_eq!(vector.len(), 3);
```

So, what's the difference between the two... why use one and not the other?

Comment: i think count actually counts and len fetches the length

Answer (score 42):

[vector.len()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.len)

> Returns the number of elements in the vector.

[iter.len()](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html#tymethod.len)

> Return the exact length of the iterator.

[iter.count()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.count)

> Counts the number of elements in this iterator.

So while they return the same value, `count` will actually count the elements. Note that `len` is available only for ExactSizeIterator; so if the value is lazy-retrieved the total length may not be available and you need to explicitly count it.

Comment: `.iter().len()` does not (immediately) call `Vec::len()`.

Comment: So if you call `.len()` on a lazy value will it invoke `.count()` internally? EDIT: Or would `.len()` not even exist for such a value?

Comment: The `iter.len()` is provided by a trait, so on lazy value it will not exist.

Comment: Pleanse, correct me if I'm wrong: both `len()` methods have a constant time complexity while `count` is lineal?

Comment: @Genarito Must be. The docs say "This method will call next repeatedly until None is encountered", so the number of calls rise linearly with the number of elements

Comment: Thank you! Also it worth to metion that `len` in structs that implements [ExactSizeIterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html) is also BigO constant

Comment: vector.len() link is broken